# Laravel 5.1 cron not workin in OVH

Tags: php, laravel-5, ovh

I'm trying to run a cron in my OVH but it is not accepting the command :

```
php artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Error occured :

[image]

it say :

```
The characters for the records are letters , numbers, and characters -_./ Moreover , it is forbidden to access parent folders
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question

Comment: @AbrarJahin I've updated an image showing the error. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Use the example on the Laravel docs with the full path to your working directory:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling

Comment: it is still now working. it is not allowing to add space in the field. As soon as I put a space it throws error. It is working in my server but in OVH its bad.

Comment: @Pranab - seems like a problem with OVH's Control Panel then. You could try putting quotes round the command, but otherwise it could be an OVH support issue.

Comment: it is still the same. Putting quotes around the command is also not working.

Comment: @Pranab - seems like a hosting issue so maybe this will help http://help.ovh.co.uk/HostingCron but I'm out.

Comment: its not working the hosting provider told me to use cron.php or something similar. How can I use a .php for cron in Laravel.

Comment: @Pranab - that would be a different question, which you should raise with the SO community

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Create a file `cron.php` with these contents</strike>

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
exec('php /path/to/artisan schedule:run', $output);
print_r($output);
```

<strike>Make sure to edit the `/path/to` part. Then enter cron.php in "command to be executed" field in "Add a scheduling" window.</strike>

[image: ovh control panel add cron job]

---

<strike>If you run into error, try checking permissions for `cron.php` and `artisan`. Permission can be fixed using these commands.</strike>

```
$ chmod 777 cron.php
$ chmod 777 /path/to/artisan
```

---

**Just follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37106096/2644202)**