# Artisan::call() outside the Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-artisan

I want to create a cron job for **Laravel 5.2**

My shared host (on OVH), only allows me to point to the full path of a file, and I am not able to use the recommended Cron entry from Laravel's docs, ie :

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Therefore, I have to call the Artisan command from a .php file, outside of the Laravel framework.

Here is what my `public/cron.php` file looks like so far:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

Artisan::call('refresh');
```

*`refresh` being my command for regenerating thumbnails inside my app.*

When accessing cron.php through my browser (testing on local XAMPP), the following error occurs:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:210

Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\site\public\cron.php(7): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('call', Array) 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 210
```

---

I have also tried to boot the app, but it doesn't make any differences

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$app->boot();
```

---

To avoid using the Artisan Facade, I tried calling the underlying Kernel Class directly:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;

$kernel = new Kernel;
$kernel->call('refresh');
```

But this returns:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel
```

---

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of OVH cron interface. The cron task is customized by OVH and only allows to point to the fullpath uri of a file - which file would execute my artisan command-. My question is, what should I put in this file, and should it be a PHP file, or a CMD?

[image: OVH cron interface]

Comment: So you can't edit your crontab with 'crontab -e'? How will you execute your .file periodically if you cannot create cronjobs?

Comment: @codedge OP said he owns a shared hosting at OVH. OVH lets customers create cron jobs in their Manager. `crontab -e ` is just a shortcut to open `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>` with favorite text editor. There are many other ways to put some contents in that file. Obviously, a script can handle it too.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: I see on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062141/laravel-session-files-not-cleaning-from-the-framework-sessions-folder) that you are on OVH Pro. This hosting normally comes with SSH access: check your manager... User is the same as for FTP and password should the same too.

Via SSH, you can use `crontab -e` to run artisan command of you choice using standard syntax and following Laravel documentation.

Comment: @Arcesilas I am not comfortable enough with SSH yet, I am still a FTP newbie user, but I'll start learning very soon. For now, your other answer is very satisfying, thx!

Comment: @Arcesilas By the way, do you have any idea on what is going wrong on my other question with the session files? I use multisites on OVH, and they are placed at the route of my OVH host, and not in the `www` folder (for security, because the `www` folder is publicly available from `mynickname.cluster005.ovh.net` and I dont want my sites to be available from `www/site1`, `www/site2`...). So I was thinking that maybe only the files inside `www` folder are writable, and maybe not the one outside (at the root)?

Comment: I've done some search about your other question, but not much for now, no obvious idea came to me. I will have a look, but maybe I'll need some more details... See you on your other question ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want to do is run a specific Artisan command from within a script.

You can achieve this by copying `artisan.php` and forcing the input to what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

$status = $kernel->handle(
    $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput(['command' => 'refresh']),
    new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
);

$kernel->terminate($input, $status);

exit($status);
```

If you compare this script to artisan.php, you'll see that I've just forced the input passed to `$kernel->handle()` method. It does not read the input from the CLI anymore, it takes these arguments, as an array. See [Symfony Console Component documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#calling-an-existing-command) for more details.

If you need to pass arguments to your script, just set the input accordingly:

```
$input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput([
    'command' => 'refresh',
    'arg_foo' => 'foo',
    '--option_bar' => 42
]);

$status = $kernel->handle(
    $input,
    new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
);
```

Now, you can put this script where you want, it does not need to be accessible through web via a browser (it should not, by the way).

If you put it at the root of your hosting at OVH, I mean NOT in www, you just have to fill the form very simply:

[image: OVH Shared Hosting Cronjob - Step 1]

If you want your script to be accessible through the web (which is not recommanded for obvious security reasons, but still), place it in your `www` directory, change the paths to `bootstrap/autoload.php` and `bootstrap/app.php` and give your script a name that is not easy to guess.

In the form in the OVH manager, don't forget to add `www/` at the beginning of the path of the script.

There is no need to specify `php script_name`, since the manager handles it for you, when you choose PHP version. Just type the path of the script PHP will execute.

Comment: Merci ! That's exactly what I was looking for. Very clear step by step explanation, everything works perfectly.

Comment: I have to wait 3 more hours before I can deliver the bounty, but you'll definitely get it ;)

Comment: Thanks ! Glad it helped !

Comment: In your first snipper you have this line `$kernel->terminate($input, $status);`, can you please explain me where does the `$input` come from?

Comment: My mistake. It's old now, and I don't have the code anymore... I think I just forgot to copy correctly the `$input` declaration in the `$status` declaration (yeah, declaration inside another declaration, as in the original `artisan` file). I've fixed the snippet.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, I'm in the same scenario but how to get logs for this ? I have an error status code of 255.

Comment: The error code is returned by your command. Symfony/Console does [not create it for you](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/1d0045219173d36244cf55906b5bcbfda5830faf/Application.php#L110)

Answer (score 2):

Just try simple:

```
shell_exec('php artisan refresh');
```

If it doesn't work, try to add appropriate paths to both `php` and `artisan`.

Comment: This works perfectly on my localhost, but when I try on production, it 'breaks' the website and I then I get random 500 errors appearing when browsing. Here are the logs from the host:


`FastCGI: comm with server "/home/xxx.com/public/cron-refresh.php" aborted: idle timeout (300 sec)`

`FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/home/xxx.com/public/cron-refresh.php"`

`FastCGI: An error happend on Fastcgi processing, fallback to CGI`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want set a cron job. please edit crontab and use "your/app/path/php artisan cron:job" to excute your command directly.