# Laravel Artisan call from PHP without CLI terminal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I would like to use a program (Freescout) as a Laravel program. 
It works fine, except 
I have to make a cron job:
`* * * * * php /var/userdata/web/.../website/helpdesk/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

, but I can't run it in terminal, can't use any CLI, just set up a Cron to run PHP script. 
(shared hosting server).

So I've created a file called *artisan_schedule_runner.php*
It would simple do:

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    Artisan::call('schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1');
    //
});
```

How should I extend my code to get it work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it's not the code problem, but it's because your hosting disables your cronjob. Usually, shared hosting will block cronjob that runs every minute.

Comment: did you try to call `shell_exec`?

Comment: artisan is a php script. Why do you want to create another one? So your problem is, that you cannot run any crons any want to run it when visiting a certain route. Did I get that correct?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  If you want to run jobs on a schedule, [set up the scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling).

Comment: I can make a cron to run a script as an URL. How can I pass the 'schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1' parameter with URL?

Comment: Did you look at the docs I linked to?  1) [Set up the scheduler, add the cron job to run it](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#introduction).  2) [Write a console script to do whatever you want](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan). 3) [Schedule that script to run](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands). It is all in the docs I linked to.  If that is not what you are asking, please edit your question and try to clarify.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I looked at all the docs, and I read that I need to run console commands. The problem is that as I pointed out in the question: I can't run any console command, just only PHP scripts. If I misunderstood anything, please help me to make a PHP script that runs the previously Laravel-scheduled tasks (those already done).

Comment: @A.El-zahaby I tried, it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found the solution, and made my question solved:
[Artisan::call() outside the Laravel framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061770/artisancall-outside-the-laravel-framework?rq=1)

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class); 
$input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput(['command' => 'schedule:run']);
$output = new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput(fopen('output.log', 'a', false)); 
$status = $kernel->handle( $input, $output );
```

That runs the prevously defined schedules.